# task :something => :environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Can someone explain me what happens when I add such dependency to my tasks? Which files are loaded etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this dependency does is requiring your config/environment.rb file, ie. loading the entire Rails environment. You can do this whenever you need to use any code from your application in the rake tasks (ie. models), which is quite common.